# How to check if an IP address is EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, solr

We have an IP address in configuration file (which hosts a solr server that accepts requests at a specific port). The developer who has added that IP address in the configuration file in the source code has left the company. I feel that it might be an EC2 instance, how-ever when I logged into EC2 dashboard, I don't see any with that IP address. Perhaps, I didn't check at all the places that I need to. 
How can I find if that ip address is an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could run `nslookup <ip address>` in the terminal. If it's an ec2 IP address will have a name like ec2-ip.instance_location.compute.amazonaws.com.

Comment: Yes, but that ec2-ip.instance_location.compute.amazonaws.com  that I achieved is not available in my AWS dashboard. :-( .

Comment: Have you tried looking on the list of your elastic IPs? Not always an elastic IP is linked to an EC2 instance (although its highly recommended to avoid extra charges that comes with it). For instance, if the server is behind a vpn I could create a separate elastic ip to route traffic through (and decide not to link it to any instance).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to determine this is to crossreference your IP with Amazon's public IP list.

You can start here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download

Comment: Using nslookup, I could see that its an AWS EC2  instance, but I can't see it in the list of my machines in the dashboard.